# (Proof-verification) A complete metric space is closed

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces

I am trying to prove the following proposition: Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space, and let $(Y,d)$  be a subspace. If $(Y,d)$ is complete, then $Y$ must be closed in $X$. 

 What I have tried to do: 
 let $$x_1,x_2 \in Y \text{ and let  } d(x_1, x_2) = r$$ we find a sequence of decreasing non negative real numbers such that $$\epsilon_1 > \epsilon_2>...$$ and use this to make another sequence $(x^{(i)})_{i=1}^\infty $ such that $x^1 = x_1 \ \text{ and } d(x^i, x^{i+1})=r-\epsilon_i$ . The latter sequence is a Cauchy sequence and since $Y$ is a complete set, the sequence converges to $x_2$. Thus $x_2$ is an adherent point (either an interior point or a boundary point). So every point in $Y$ is an adherent point which implies that it is closed.

Is this proof correct ?

Comment: In general you cannot construct a sequence with prescribed distances from the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume by contradiction that $Y$ is not closed in $X$.

By definition, $X\setminus Y$ is not open, so there exists $x\in X\setminus Y$ with the following property:
for every $r>0$, the open ball $B_r(x)$ is not contained in $X\setminus Y$.
In other words,
$$
B_r(x) \cap Y \neq \emptyset \qquad \forall r > 0.
$$
For every $k\in\mathbb{N}$ we can the find a point $x_k \in Y$ such that $d(x_k, x) < 1/k$.

Hence the sequence $(x_k)\subset Y$ converges, in $(X,d)$, to the point $x$, so that it is a Cauchy sequence in $(X,d)$ and so also in $(Y,d)$.
On the other hand, this sequence is not convergent in $(Y,d)$, a contradiction since $(Y,d)$ is complete.

Answer (score 0):

No. Your proof very strange. Take a convergent sequence $(y_n)$ in $Y$ with limit $y_0$. We have to show that $y_0 \in Y$. Since $Y$ is complete and since $(y_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $Y$, there is $z_0 \in Y$ such that $y_n \to z_0$. It follows that $y_0=z_0$, hence $y_0 \in Y$.